# MutableLiveData sets value but getValue() returns null?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, nullpointerexception, android-livedata

I face this problem after migrating my project to `androidx`. It all worked like a charm before the migration *(i **had** to migrate my project)* but now i stand before this weird problem that didnt exist 10min earlier.

**Scenario:**
Fragment 1 contains a listview of items and when user click on item i call my viewmodels `setvalue()` method and then fragment 2 appears to show the item user clicked on and for this i call my viewmodels `getvalue()`. The scenario is very simple.

**Fragment 1:**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        viewModel.getClickedSong().setValue(viewModel.getSongs().getValue().get(position));
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
public MutableLiveData<Song> getClickedSong() {
    if (clickedSong == null) {
        clickedSong = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return clickedSong;
}
```

**Fragment 2:**

```
viewModel.getClickedSong().observe(this, new Observer<Song>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Song song) {
                    mySong = song;
```

I also tried: `mySong = viewModel.getClickedSong().getValue()` but this also returns null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of researching, testing etc. the fix was quite simple.

I changed this line of code:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

To this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
```

Comment: As you can see, the problem isn't with ```MutableLiveData```, but with your ```ViewModel```. Since it's a ```SharedViewModel```, you need to have it's ```LifeCycleOwner``` set to either an ```Activity``` or to your ```Application``` class. This way, if you reuse that ```LifeCycleOwner``` with that ```ViewModel```, the changes of your ```LiveData``` properties will be visible to your other ```Activities``` or ```Fragment```s.

Comment: It is better to use `Hilt` to inject the ViewModel nowadays, rather than `ViewModelProviders`